# How do I check if the SSD on my APFS volume is using DRAT or DZAT?

Tags: macos, ssd, trim

DZAT: Deterministic zero after TRIM.
DRAT: Deterministic read after TRIM.

Details on TRIM [here](https://articles.forensicfocus.com/2014/09/23/recovering-evidence-from-ssd-drives-in-2014-understanding-trim-garbage-collection-and-exclusions/).

Comment: Seems like this would be way too broad to answer in a short post, but l’m not going to close it unilaterally at this point. Feel free to review the “how to ask for off site resources” on [meta] and consider showing your work to explain what specific steps you have working. I stopped counting words on the linked article at 6000 so that doesn’t really help us know what help you need here.

Comment: So glad that Allan delivered a great answer. Hopefully he pinpointed what you wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can send an [`ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing)#ATA) to your SATA attached device (your SSD) and words 69 and 169 should provide you the information you're looking for.

**However.....[There is no way to do this on macOS/OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/WorkingWithSAM/WWS_SAMDevInt/WWS_SAM_DevInt.html)**

> **By design, OS X does not allow applications to send SCSI or ATA
>   commands to storage devices unless the application developer also
>   provides an in-kernel device driver that supports the commands.** The
>   SCSI Architecture Model family allows only one logical unit driver to
>   control a device at a time and provides in-kernel logical unit drivers
>   for storage devices (as listed in SCSI Architecture Model Family
>   Device Support). Similarly, the ATA family does not allow applications
>   to send ATA commands directly to ATA or SATA (Serial ATA) devices.

What this means is that there's no built-in or 3rd party utility that will allow you to query the device directly (with the exception of SMART status values).

It may be possible in other OSes (Windows, Linux, or BSD) but Apple, by design, doesn't allow you to get this info.  Your best bet is to get this information from the manufacturer.