# Tell age of SSD by using iostat?

Tags: ssd

I did

> iostat  -Id disk0

on my MacBook Pro (MacOS Sierra) and found the total number of reads/writes done on the SSD. Is it true that this is indicative of the age of the MacBook? Should a new MacBook have very few reads/writes? Mine has a power cycle count of 10 but a very high number of transfers (2050247) at 28.6 KB/t i.e. around 55GB worth of reads and writes. Something seems off here...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Kindly edit the question to include some important details such as model of your MacBook, mode of acquisition and ownership (new vs. refurbished, personal vs. company owned), mode of usage (do you use plugged-in all the time) etc. That will better help in answering the question.

Comment: This info is held in the SMART attributes; `iostat` is not necessarily the best tool for the job. If you reformat the drive (or put it in a different machine) `iostat` statistics are reset to zero because it’s what the *operating system* measured.   See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/336702/119271

Answer (score 0):

No, iostat gets it's information from the OS, not from the hardware.

You could use `smartctl` - [see this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/135566/10713)